# the two codes are similar,why the first is wrong?

Tags: c++

Input
each test case contains two numbers A and B. **these two numbers may be more than 5000 bits**

Output for each case, if A is equal to B, you should print "YES", or print "NO".

Sample Input

1 2
2 2
3 3
4 3

Sample Output

NO
YES
YES
NO

I've tried many times,the output is correct but why it's a wrong answer when I submit it?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

string cut(string X)
{
    long i; 
        if(X.find(".")!=X.npos)
        {
            i=X.length();
            while((X[--i]=='0'||X[i]=='.')&&i >0) X.erase(i,1); 
        }
        while((X[0]=='0')&&X.length()>1) X.erase(0,1);
        if(X==".") X="0";
    return X;
}

int main()
{
    string A,B;
    while(cin>>A>>B)
   {
            if(cut(A)==cut(B)) cout<<"YES"<<endl;
            else cout<<"NO"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

why the one above is not correct while this code below is right?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string a, b;
char t;
long i;

int
main (void) {
    while (cin >> a >> b) {
        if (a.find(".") != a.npos) {
            i = a.length();
            while ((a[--i] == '0' || a[i] == '.') && i > 0) {
                t = a[i];
                a.erase(i, 1);
                if (t == '.') break;
            }
        }
        if (b.find(".") != b.npos) {
            i = b.length();
            while ((b[--i] == '0' || b[i] == '.') && i > 0) {
                t = b[i];
                b.erase(i, 1);
                if (t == '.') break;
            }
        }
        while ((a[0] == '0') && a.length() > 1) {a.erase(0, 1);}
        while ((b[0] == '0') && b.length() > 1) {b.erase(0, 1);}
        if (a == ".") a = "0";
        if (b == ".") b = "0";
        if (a == b) cout << "YES" << endl;
        else cout << "NO" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `cut()` do? Why are you looking for a `.` in the input when there isn't one?

Comment: Because there is no `iostream` header?

Comment: because it needs us to think of these situations:0.000010000 and 0.00001.or 0000.0000 and 0 . Or it would be wrong if I just do the simplest comparing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The two numbers may be over 5000 bits." This is in C not C++ but most of the code will be the same. It strips the leading and trailing stuff from the input, but does not process actual numbers, just numeric strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char a [10000];
char b [10000];

char *strip (char *str)
// remove unnecessary leading and trailing chars from a number string
// return pointer to first significant char
{
    int z;

    // strip leading numeric zeros
    while (*str=='0')
        str++;

    // strip trailing zeros after (and/or including) decimal point
    if (strrchr (str, '.'))
        for (z=strlen(str)-1; z>=0; z--) {
            if (str[z] == '.') {
                str[z] = 0;          // truncate
                break;
            }
            if (str[z] !='0') {
                str[z+1] = 0;          // truncate
                break;
            }
        }
    return str;
}

int main(void)
{
    scanf ("%s%s", a, b);
    if (strcmp (strip(a), strip(b)) == 0)
         printf ("YES\n");
    else printf ("NO\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why on earth don't you simply do:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    int a, b;
    while (std::cin >> a >> b) {
        std::cout << (a == b ? "YES" : "NO");
    }
 }
```

Comment: because it needs me to think of many situations like these:0.010000 and 0.01 or 01203 and 1203....if I wrote like what you post,it would be a wrong answer.

Comment: If you want 01203 not to equal 1203 then just compare them as strings. If you want to compare the numeric value, @Paul is correct.

Comment: 01203 is equal to 1203 and 0.0000 is equal to 0...I can't just use int or double  to compare them..

Comment: @Jacqueline What makes you think that you can't use `double`?

Comment: **the two numbers may be over 5000 bits...**

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If you want it for cases like **0123 be equal with 123** or **0.0200004 equal with 000.020000400000** then use this:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    float A, B;

    while (std::cin >> A >> B) 
    {
        if(A != B)
        {   
            std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {   
            std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: 01203 is equal to 1203 and 0.0000 is equal to 0...I can't just use int or double to compare them..

Comment: @Jacqueline then use float.

Comment: I just posted what you wrote,it's also wrong,I feel confused